# get image data uploaded from url

Tags: php

I'm trying to write a form where a user can upload an image from a url.  I know how to upload the image using fopen and fwrite, but I have no idea how to get/check other information about the file such as the filesize, mime type, file extension etc before the file has actually been uploaded.  Is this even possible?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pathinfo should do the trick for you. http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Comment: `pathinfo()` won't provide the MIME type

Comment: MIME type is a bit more difficult but you could check that with Fileinfo (http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) @chris

Comment: Or use `getimagesize()` as my answer suggests. `getimagesize()` added MIME type in PHP 4.3.0. It's not difficult at all.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least a couple of methods, but the simplest one that will give you everything you specifically mention is [getimagesize()](http://www.php.net/getimagesize)

```
$info = getimagesize( 'image.png' );
print_r( $info );
```

pathinfo() won't give you the MIME type.

Comment: getimagesize gets the mime type easily, but print_r($info) only shows the dimensions, bits, channels and mime type - no filesize or extension.